# Using IIS 7.5 as an HTTP Proxy Server?

Tags: iis, proxy

Is there any way to use IIS 7.5 as an HTTP Proxy Server ? Actually i'm using SquidNT, but i'm looking for a IIS based solution.

Answer (score 0):

No. IIS is a web server, not a proxy server. There is a module for it that can be used to create a reverse proxy, but that's about it. Check out ISA if you want a proxy server from Microsoft.